# RSpec 3 acceptance testing approach without "its" blocks

Tags: ruby, csv, rspec

I have a doubt about how to test a simple CSV importer without using the `its(:...)` clause.

In RSpec 2.x, my approach was to set the imported object as the subject of my spec, and then test each attribute in a `its(...)` block. It was an acceptance-like test, but it served me well, and I didn't want to unit test the library I used to do my CSV parsing, as it was really a trivial implementation, so I was ok with an end-to-end test.

Now, with RSpec 3, I can make this spec pass with transpec, but I read [the explanation about why the its block has been removed](https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509) and I think RSpec 3 is suggesting a different approach, right? So how would you test that?

I don't think a lot of ugly blocks like this

```
describe '#email' do
  subject { super().email }
  it { is_expected.to eq("john_doe@email.com") }
end
```

are any better than

```
its(:email) { should == "john.doe@email.com" }
```

as they do exactly the same thing.

I've read that you need to test "behaviour", but how about acceptance tests? What's the suggested way to go here?
Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with `it 'has some email' { expect(subject.email).to eq("john_doe@email.com") }`?

Comment: @UriAgassi - thanks! Yes, you are right. `specify { expect(subject.email).to eq("john_doe@email.com") }` is a correct solution. I wanted to know how to accomplish what Myron Marston pointed out in the article I linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Myron suggests using [`rspec-given`](https://github.com/jimweirich/rspec-given) for a one-liner rich test suite. Using this package, your tests will look something like this:

```
Given(:email) { subject.email }

context "sign up" do
  When { subject.sign_up(email: "john.doe@email.com") }

  Then { email == "john.doe@email.com" }
end
```

Comment: oh god, that's so ugly.

Comment: Mmm... I agree with @sevenseacat :D I mean, if that's the way to go, I like the RSpec 2.x syntax a lot more! But thanks for writing this Uri :)

Answer (score 0):

While the `its` functionality has been removed from rspec-core, it has been put into an includable gem, `rspec-its`.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-its

I would just include this gem and keep writing tests the way you have been - I find them the most readable.

ps. Unrelated but I would also always use `eq` instead of `==` in specs :)